# How do I stop a Bootstrap multiple carousel slide banner to a single image banner?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the carousel in Bootstrap. I just want it to be like single image for banner.

I tried this CSS code:

```css
item:active {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can have a [Bootstrap Carousel](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp) with only one image. I guess you are trying to take advantage from class/es **carousel, slide, carousel-inner** or so and if it fits to your needs, you can create simple carousel without any arrows or controls :

```
<div class="container">
 <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
   <div class="item active">
    <img src="la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width: 100%;">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```